# how to make sure the tx to be included in block

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, eosio-code, cpu, contract-development

as subject, any way to make sure the tx to be included in block, what i think of is, if the tx meet the condition, then notify the contract to execute the specified action, otherwise notify an account without contract deployed, the questions is any way to save the cpu resource if the tx do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

to get a better understand of how transactions make it to a block please read the following series of FAQs starting with [this one](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/faq/index/#should-we-use-the-block-number-returned-by-rpc-to-confirm-if-a-transaction-is-added-to-a-block) and all that follow till the end.

I hope it will help understand the topic better.

Answer (score 0):

On-chain CPU resource is only used if the transaction is successful.